# Switch to new browser opened after click on a button [Python][Selenium]

Tags: python, windows, selenium

I have a situation where I click on a button that opens up a new browser Window. Is there any way to connect to the newly opened  window? And work with it, then return back to original browser (first window).

Thank you.

After some thorough investigation on the net I managed to get some of the code working

```
Currentwindow = driver.window_handles
Likebutton = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".single_like_button .btn3").click()
newwindow = driver.window_handles
newwindow = list(set(newwindow) - set(Currentwindow))[0]
driver.switch_to.window(newwindow)
driver.find_element_by_id("watch-like").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.close()
```

Problem is the command `driver.implicitly_wait(5)` doesn't work for some reason and the page automatically closes which is not something I want.
How do I get it working?

Answer (score 4):

```
driver.switch_to.window(handle)
```

switches the focus to the specified window. `handle` can be a name or window handle.

You can use

```
driver.window_handles
```

to find a list of window handles.

There are also these functions which you may find useful:

```
driver.switch_to.active_element     
driver.switch_to.default_content    
driver.switch_to.parent_frame   
driver.switch_to.alert 
driver.switch_to.frame 
driver.switch_to.window
```

Comment: Updated with another issue

Answer (score 1):

too late for you , but maybe this will help someone

```
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
```

this command wait , while the page is loaded or 5 sec.
If it will be loaded in 1 sec , then

```
driver.close()
```

Run after 1 second .
If it be loaded in 7 sec , then

```
driver.close()
```

Run after 5 sec

You may use

```
import time

time.sleep(5)
```

It will wait exactly 5 sec anyway